# How to turn off gesture show Navigation bar on tablet

Tags: android, gesture, tablet

On android tablet gesture from bottom to top - show navigation bar.
How to turn off programmatically?

Comment: you can't, as it will prevent the users from exiting your app in some cases.

Comment: what if with ROOT?

Comment: that's another question. But you will need to modify some settings out of Android SDK scope.

Comment: ок
Thank you
I thought so